# unable to revere proxy jenkins using apache

Tags: apache, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I have installed `Jenkins` and `apache2` on my `Ubuntu-16.04 server`and both are working fine. Now i want to deploy or configure reverse proxy for jenkins using apache.

Took help from this [site](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-jenkins-with-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04/) to configure. I configured everything as per my need. My configuration file under `sites-available` folder `ci.conf` looks like

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName        jenkins.tre.com
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://jenkins.tre.com/
</Virtualhost>
```

and system `hostname` abd `domain name` is

```
root@tre:~# hostname
tre
root@tre:~# domainname
(none)
```

When i restarted `apache & jenkins` and tried to access `http://jenkins.tre.com/` the page is not opening, can anyone help me with this.... since iam very much new in to this thing.

Comment: I think you need to enable this site configuarion. Go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and run the following command: `sudo a2ensite jenkins.tre.com`

Then reload apache: `sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: @ANILMAHAPATRAOfficial, i did that by executing `a2ensite ci` then reloaded and restarted the apache

Comment: So, now is it working?

Comment: Nope its not working.....